# Native Heap Maximum size and release of memory

Tags: android

I am a little bit confused about the native heap on android, I would 
like know the native heap max size, there is a way to know it?

Like

```
getRuntime().maxMemory()
```

which I use for know the maximum limit  of VM heap.

Another question is relative at how the native heap memory is 
released, I read that IS NOT the GC of Dalvik which free that memory, 
is correct? If yes, when the memory of native heap is released? 
Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestion. 
pedr0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this issues.

For see the native heap in DDMS you have to run the DDMS standalone and add this line at the file ddms.cfg :

```
native=true
```

After that you will see that "Native Heap" Tab in DDMS.

Bye!

Comment: Wow this is a great tip! I hope it gets more visibility! We couldn't find out where our application was leaking memory, and we knew it was because of Android bitmaps not being recycled on the native side.

Comment: It's actually a bit more complicated than that, as this article shows: http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/2012/04/25/how-to-enable-native-heap-tracking-in-ddms/